# getting error when creating VM in Azure RM using an existing image using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I am creating a new VM using Azure RM from a copied image; the error is:

New-AzureRMVM : Source and destination storage accounts for disk osdisk are different.
StatusCode: 409
ReasonPhrase: Conflict
OperationID : 'c55f44a7-b46c-423c-aa52-6bb8a99391ee'

- New-AzureRMVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Location $location -VM $vm
- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ComputeCloudException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand

what am I missing?

Comment: steps:
1. create storage account in AR subscription
2. copy custom vhd to this storage account
3. create VM using the VHD from step (2)

fyi: source and dest are on different subscription/resourcegroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its in the error message, it not posible to deploy a vhd from a diffrent storage account when creating a VM.

You will have to copy the VHD over to the same storage account the VM will run out of before you start to deploy the VHD.

Copy past from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/

> Note: The VM needs to be in the same storage account as the uploaded
>   VHD file.

To fix it, you can do something along these lines before you deploy the first VM:

```
$SourceContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $VhdSourceResouceGroup -StorageAccountName $VhdSourceStorageAccount).Context

$DestinationContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $VhdStorageAccount).Context

New-AzureStorageContainer -Name "source" -Context $DestinationContext -ErrorAction Ignore

Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy `
            -SrcUri "$($SourceContext.BlobEndPoint)source/$Image" `
            -SrcContext $SourceContext `
            -DestContainer "source" `
            -DestBlob $Image -ConcurrentTaskCount 24 `
            -DestContext $DestinationContext | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState -WaitForComplete
```